# how to find largest and smallest primenumber in my Number.txt file?how to read the file?

Tags: java, loops

I am creating a "Numberfile.txt" and input (write) numbers and a class to find the largest and smallest prime number.

How can I access and read the numbers, and find the largest and smallest number?

```
public class CheckP {
    void Check() throws IOException
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Numberfile.txt"));

        int x;
        while (s.hasNext()) 
        {   
            x(s.nextInt()); 
            boolean isPrime(int s) {
                for(int i=2;i<s;i++) {
                    if(s%i==0)
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the largest and smallest number from my text file...

Comment: Please explain any issues you are experiencing with your current code, with any suitable error messages.

Comment: please give correct code.. i think my code was incorrect.. please solve my problem?

Comment: What is the structure of the txt file ?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show what you tried and how it fails (see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move the `isPrime()` method outside the `check()` method, it won't compile at all this way.

Next, have a look at following while loop, it should get you on your way:

```
int largest = 0;
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
while (s.hasNextInt()) 
{   
  x = s.nextInt(); 

  if(isPrime(x)){
    if(x > largest){
      largest = x;
    }
    if(x < smallest){
      smallest = x;
    }
  }
}
```